# Scala and UnionTypes bound to a generic type

Tags: scala, scalaz

The scenario:

We have different classes `A`,`B`,`C` which have *no* common base class but they all provide a method `foo` which accepts one parameter of the same type as the class itself and returns a value of type `Boolean`.

Then we want to come up with a rather complex method `bar` which accepts three parameters which should all be of the same type, i.e. either all three parameters are of type `A`, or `B`, or `C` but not a mixture of them.

The idea (which does not compile):

```
import scalaz.UnionTypes._

class A { def foo(y: A): Boolean = ??? }
class B { def foo(y: B): Boolean = ??? }
class C { def foo(y: C): Boolean = ??? }

class Foo {

  type T <: t[A]#t[B]#t[C]

  def bar(x: T, y: T, z: T) = x.foo(y) && y.foo(z) // do more complex stuff
}
```

Of course I could solve this problem by implementing the method `bar` three times

```
def bar(x: A, y: A, z: A) = x.foo(y) && y.foo(z) // do more complex stuff
def bar(x: B, y: B, z: B) = x.foo(y) && y.foo(z) // do more complex stuff
def bar(x: C, y: c, z: C) = x.foo(y) && y.foo(z) // do more complex stuff
```

but since it is a rather *complex* method I do not want to duplicate the code.

I had hoped that UnionTypes from scalaz might help in this situation but I get a compile time error. Does someone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [type class pattern](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/05/28/scala-type-classes-demystified/):

```
trait CanFoo[T] {
  def foo(x: T, y: T): Boolean
}

object CanFoo {
  implicit val ACanFoo: CanFoo[A] = new CanFoo[A] {
    def foo(x: A, y: A) = x.foo(y)
  }

  // similar definitions for B and C
}

class Foo {
  def bar[T](x: T, y: T, z: T)(implicit canFoo: CanFoo[T]) = 
    canFoo.foo(x, y) && canFoo.foo(y, z)
}
```

Comment: why would you call it a pattern? :)

Comment: @ErikAllik It isn't a pattern, it's an application of one. If you are asking why the type class pattern is considered a pattern, it's because it fits the definition :) In e.g. Haskell type classes are a first-class part of the language; in Scala they have to be encoded from similar parts arranged in a similar way each time.